# manage QML Repeater from python

Tags: python, qml, pyside2

I've been trying to make for example 10 different elements for example buttons and I could do that using the repeater but I've been having trouble with setting the text for each new element.

I'm getting the texts I want to set from a list in Python and I sent them to qml through `QStringListModel`. The text got to qml from the list as I wanted, but somehow the repeater set's the text of all the elements as the last string in the list given from Python.

I will provide the code later for extra explanation but for now I want to see if someone have idea how I can do it...(the thing is that the code is in another device and I'm waiting for it). Basically what I'm trying to do is, let's say for example, I have a list in python `a_list = {buttonName, buttonAge, buttonHeight}` and I want to make multiple buttons in `qml` as the size of the list (in this case 3) and change each text of the buttons i made in the repeater as the strings in the list).

this is main.py

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

from foo import FooController

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    fooController = FooController()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("fooController", fooController)

    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile('main.qml'))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is foo.py

```
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Property, Slot

class x:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

class FooController(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)

        self.__text = "Foo"
        self.__name = s1.name
        self.__age = s1.age

    @Property(str)
    def text(self):
        return self.__name

    @Slot()
    def clickListener(self):
        print(self.__name)
```

This is foo.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
Button {
    text: fooController.text
    onClicked: fooController.clickListener()
}
```

and here is the qml window that contains the repeater

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import "../components"
//import QtQuick.Timeline 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import "../main.py"

window{
    width: 1500
    height: 920
    minimumWidth: 1100
    minimumHeight: 650
    visible: true
    color: "#00000000"
    id: mainWindow
    title: qsTr("--")
    Rectangle{
            id: rectangle
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.rightMargin: 0
            anchors.bottomMargin: 0
            anchors.leftMargin: 0
            anchors.topMargin: 0
            radius: 10
            color: "#4642b6"
            Flickable {
                id: flickable
                contentHeight: gridLayoutBottom.height
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                anchors.topMargin: 96
                anchors.rightMargin: 8
                anchors.leftMargin: 8
                anchors.bottomMargin: 8
                clip: true
                ListModel {
                            id: imageModel

                            ListElement { _id: "tile0" }


                        }
                Repeater {
                        model: imageModel
                        delegate: CustomMenuType{
                            ListView{
                                model: s

                                delegate: Text {
                                    text: model.display
                                    font.family: "Segoe UI"
                                    color: "#ffffff"
                                }
                            }

                            //text: ListView.delegate.Text.text
                            font.pointSize: 9
                            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter

                        }
               }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Disclaimer: The code you provide is useless since it does not show any attempt to solve your problem, besides that there are undefined elements that I will not take as a basis for my answer, and it is a shame because you always learn more by correcting errors.</sub>

If you want to handle the information that the Repeater uses from Python then you must use a model. The Repeater supports 3 types of models:

- A number,
- A list or
- An object that inherits from QAbstractItemModel.

In this case the first does not provide important information since it only indicates the number of elements so it will not show it since it is a trivial example.

In the case of the list the logic is to create a Q_PROPERTY of type "QVariantList" (in PyQt5 list is enough) and that has an associated signal that is emitted every time the list changes so that the view is notified and updates the painting.

```py
import os.path
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import Property, QObject, QDateTime, QTimer, QUrl, Signal
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


CURRENT_DIRECTORY = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


class Controller(QObject):
    modelChanged = Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._model = ["Text1", "Text2", "Text3"]

    @Property("QVariantList", notify=modelChanged)
    def model(self):
        return self._model

    def update_model(self, l):
        self._model = l[:]
        self.modelChanged.emit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    controller = Controller()

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("controller", controller)
    filename = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIRECTORY, "main.qml")
    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    def on_timeout():
        dt = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        l = [dt.addSecs(i).toString() for i in range(3)]
        controller.update_model(l)

    timer = QTimer(timeout=on_timeout, interval=1000)
    timer.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window{
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Column {
        Repeater {
            model: controller.model
            Button {
                text: model.modelData
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the case of QAbstractItemModel the logic is to create a QProperty of type QObject and make it constant since the model itself does not change but the information it manages. And on the QML side, the property must be accessed using the associated role, for example in the case of QStringListModel the role is "display":

```py
import os.path
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import Property, QDateTime, QObject, QStringListModel, QTimer, QUrl
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


CURRENT_DIRECTORY = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


class Controller(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._model = QStringListModel()

        self.model.setStringList(["Text1", "Text2", "Text3"])

    def get_model(self):
        return self._model

    model = Property(QObject, fget=get_model, constant=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    controller = Controller()

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("controller", controller)
    filename = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIRECTORY, "main.qml")
    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    def on_timeout():
        dt = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        l = [dt.addSecs(i).toString() for i in range(3)]
        controller.model.setStringList(l)

    timer = QTimer(timeout=on_timeout, interval=1000)
    timer.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window{
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Column {
        Repeater {
            model: controller.model
            Button {
                text: model.display
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also create a custom model but you have to declare a role associated with the data, a trivial example is to use the QStandardItemModel class.

```py
import os.path
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import (
    Property,
    QDateTime,
    QObject,
    Qt,
    QTimer,
    QUrl,
)
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication, QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


CURRENT_DIRECTORY = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

TEXT_ROLE = Qt.UserRole + 1000
DATA_ROLE = TEXT_ROLE + 1


class Controller(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.model.setItemRoleNames({TEXT_ROLE: b"text", DATA_ROLE: b"data"})
        for i in range(3):
            item = QStandardItem()
            item.setData("Text{}".format(i), TEXT_ROLE)
            item.setData(i, DATA_ROLE)
            self.model.appendRow(item)

    def get_model(self):
        return self._model

    model = Property(QObject, fget=get_model, constant=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    controller = Controller()

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("controller", controller)
    filename = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIRECTORY, "main.qml")
    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    def on_timeout():
        dt = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        for i in range(controller.model.rowCount()):
            item = controller.model.item(i)
            item.setData(dt.addSecs(i).toString(), TEXT_ROLE)
            item.setData(dt.addSecs(i), DATA_ROLE)

    timer = QTimer(timeout=on_timeout, interval=1000)
    timer.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window{
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Column {
        Repeater {
            model: controller.model
            Button {
                text: model.text
                onClicked: console.log(model.data)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could also create a class that inherits from QAbstractListModel and overrides the data, setData, roleNames, rowCount methods.